# How to delete duplicate dates IF they contain a NULL field but keep all other duplicate dates

Tags: sql

I left joined a table (TABLE A) consisting entirely of dates with a table (TABLE B) with dates + data with - in order to have an entry for each week of the year. I know left joins will cause duplicates - but I need a way to get rid of the duplicate dates that contain a NULL field, while keeping all other dates (even if they are duplicates.

```
ROW  Start of Week| Data  |
1 |  2018-07-01   | NULL  |
2 |  2018-07-01   | data  |
3 |  2018-09-01   | NULL  |
4 |  2018-10-03   | data  |
5 |  2018-10-03   | data  |
6 |  2018-10-03   | NULL  |
------------------------
```

I'd like to keep rows 2,3,4,5

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and the query (perhaps simplified) that you are using.

Comment: Is data unique, or it can also be duplicate?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What does your join conditions look like?  If you're joining just on the date field 1 shouldn't ever happen... nor should 6.... `SELECT A.MyDate, B.Data
LEFT JOIN B
 on A.MyDate = B.BDate
and B.Data is not null`  They woudln't happen because once a date has a data in B, it can't be null...  Show sample data in both tables causing 2018-07-01 null and data.... from your query...

Comment: Why do you need to keep both 4 and 5 rows, they are duplicate rows, aren't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where datacol is not null
or not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where date = t.date and datacol is not null
)
```

For your case, you can wrap your query inside a CTE and then use NOT EXISTS:

```
with cte as (
  <your query here>
)
select c.* from cte c
where c.datacol is not null
or not exists (
  select 1 from cte
  where date = c.date and datacol is not null
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=df6e3fcc330dc8cd34f83c56f7df5710).
Results:

```
date       | datacol
01/07/2018 | data   
01/09/2018 | null
03/10/2018 | data   
03/10/2018 | data
```

Comment: THANKS! Could have worded my question better and should have provided more code, but this solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you're getting rows 1 and 6 in the first place...

You said "I know left joins will cause duplicates" Why?  The only duplicates that should occur are those with dates matching from table B.. Such as 20181003 in your example.  I don't see why you get rows 1/6 in the first place..

(Using mySQL as a DB in this [RexTester Example](https://rextester.com/QSNF40571))

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT cast("20180701" as date) as MyDate union all
      SELECT cast("20180901" as date) union all
      SELECT cast("20181003" as date)) A
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT cast("20180701" as date) as MyDate, 'data' dat union all
      SELECT cast("20181003" as date), 'data' dat union all
      SELECT cast("20181003" as date), 'data' dat) B
  on  A.MYDate = B.MyDate
```

Gives us: Result set 1

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+
|    |       MyDate        |       MyDate        | dat  |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+
|  1 | 01.07.2018 00:00:00 | 01.07.2018 00:00:00 | data |
|  2 | 01.09.2018 00:00:00 | NULL                | NULL |
|  3 | 03.10.2018 00:00:00 | 03.10.2018 00:00:00 | data |
|  4 | 03.10.2018 00:00:00 | 03.10.2018 00:00:00 | data |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+
```

No rows 1/6 there...

The only way I could see you getting rows 1/6 is if table B has blank Data (dat in my example) ... This could be eliminated by putting an additional AND condition on the left join to eliminate NULL dat records...

For example if B looked like:

```
  SELECT cast("20180701" as date) as MyDate, 'data' dat union all
  SELECT cast("20180701" as date) as MyDate, NULL dat union all
  SELECT cast("20181003" as date), 'data' dat union all
  SELECT cast("20181003" as date), 'data' dat
```

then we'd get... Result Set 2

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+
|    |       MyDate        |       MyDate        | dat  |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+
|  1 | 01.07.2018 00:00:00 | 01.07.2018 00:00:00 | data |
|  2 | 01.07.2018 00:00:00 | 01.07.2018 00:00:00 | NULL | <-- Dont' want this...
|  3 | 01.09.2018 00:00:00 | NULL                | NULL | <-- But we want this
|  4 | 03.10.2018 00:00:00 | 03.10.2018 00:00:00 | data |
|  5 | 03.10.2018 00:00:00 | 03.10.2018 00:00:00 | data |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+
```

But this could be managed by ensuring dat wasn't null in the first place...

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT cast("20180701" as date) as MyDate union all
      SELECT cast("20180901" as date) union all
      SELECT cast("20181003" as date)) A
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT cast("20180701" as date) as MyDate, 'data' dat union all
      SELECT cast("20181003" as date), 'data' dat union all
      SELECT cast("20181003" as date), 'data' dat) B
  on  A.MYDate = B.MyDate
 and B.Dat is not null  <-- so do this to solve the problem...
```

Note we can't do this in the where clause or it negates the left join; making it behave like an inner; but putting the limit on the join condition itself, we can exclude those b records with a Null date.

Giving us what we were after in the first place (Result set 1)  So either I don't understand the problem, or the problem isn't what you think it is.

So please provide a minimally complete and verifiable example (MCVE) of the problem.

Comment: Table A was a "spine" consisting of all weeks in a given year. Table B was a table consisting of data that took place on given weeks so after left joining the two, the dates in TABLE B that were also in TABLE A were duplicated although one date had data and the other was NULL (from table A). I'm ok with Null data for some weeks, if there is no match from Table B, however if they do share a date I would like to only see the week with the data and not the date with empty data columns from TABLE A.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working SQL code:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (
    [ROW] INT,
    [Start of WEEK] DATETIME,
    [data] VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @TestTable
([ROW], [Start of WEEK], [data])
VALUES
(1, '2018-07-01', NULL), 
(2, '2018-07-01', 'data1'), 
(3, '2018-09-01', NULL), 
(4, '2018-10-03', 'data2'), 
(5, '2018-10-03', 'data3'), 
(6, '2018-10-03', NULL)

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Start of WEEK] ORDER BY [Start of WEEK], data DESC) AS RowNo 
    FROM @TestTable 
) tbl
WHERE data IS NOT NULL OR RowNo = 1
ORDER BY [ROW]
```

the output of above:

```
ROW Start of WEEK           data    RowNo
2   2018-07-01 00:00:00.000 data1   1
3   2018-09-01 00:00:00.000 NULL    1
4   2018-10-03 00:00:00.000 data2   2
5   2018-10-03 00:00:00.000 data3   1
```

**Comment:** 
table declaration and insert certainly could be excluded as I used it to test on the data you provided.
All you need is to replace name @TestTable to your table name in the last statement and use only last statement

**Explanation:**
RowNo is a row number within each week and data. Note that data is ordered DESC, which means NULL will be the last row for each week. However if week has only one record with NULL it will be the only row (#1) - which is reflected in the `WHERE` statement above.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at it without knowing what your existing query or data look like. Here I make the assumption that there's a FK to tableA and that you're using SQL Server. Also, I would only use this with a relatively small data set because `distinct` is pretty resource intensive. Otherwise, I'd look for a solution using ROW_NUMBER() function.

```sql
select distinct id, date, ISNULL(dataB, dataA) data
from (
  select a.id, a.date, null as dataA, null as dataB
  from tableA
  union
  select b.id, b.date, null as dataA, b.data as dataB
  from tableB b
  where data is not null
)
```

Comment: You won't get row #3 with this approach, would you?

Comment: That left join returns regular inner join result.

Comment: @GSazheniuk you're right. I didn't read the question thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to do without your column names and such, but I'd use WHERE NOT EXISTS I've cleverly named your columns ID, theDate, and theData:

```
+----+--------------+---------+
| ID |   theDate    | theData |
+----+--------------+---------+
| 1  |  2018-07-01  |  NULL   |
| 2  |  2018-07-01  |  data   |
| 3  |  2018-09-01  |  NULL   |
| 4  |  2018-10-03  |  data   |
| 5  |  2018-10-03  |  data   |
| 6  |  2018-10-03  |  NULL   |
+----+--------------+---------+
```

So:

```
select
*
from
<your table>
where
theData is not null
union all
select 
*
from
<your table> t
where not exists (select 1 from <your table> tt where theData is not null and t.theDate = tt.theDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

This SQL is to delete only those records that have theData value null AND have multiple records (count > 1) when grouped by theDate:

```
delete yourTable
where theData is null
and theDate in
(
select theDate
from yourTable
group by theDate
having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: please provide some explanation to the answer. It is facing deletion as mentioned by @TimStack as well.